# Can not use drawtext with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m using this code to install ffmpeg with GPU support on Google colab:

```
!apt install nvidia-driver-525
!apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

!mkdir ~/nvidia/
%cd ~/nvidia/
!git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
%cd nv-codec-headers
!make install
%cd ~/nvidia/
!git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg/
!apt install build-essential yasm cmake libtool libc6 libc6-dev unzip wget libnuma1 libnuma-dev
%cd ~/nvidia/ffmpeg/

!./configure --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
!make -j $(nproc)

!ls -l ffmpeg
!./ffmpeg
!sudo make install
```

it works, except I was getting the error message `"No such filter: 'drawtext'"`, so I added the `--enable-libfreetype` option to this line:

```
!./configure  --enable-libfreetype --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

but after re-running I’m still getting the same message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `--enable-libharfbuzz` as well.

Comment: thanks. also needed to install libharfbuzz-dev before :

!apt-get install -y libharfbuzz-dev

Comment: am I missing something to add subtitles also? I’m getting an `"Error parsing filterchain"` on my `-vf subtitles=` command: 
`[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5b3ae1f8c5c0] No option name near 'subtitles.srt:force_style=FontName=Roboto Condensed Bold,FontSize=15,PrimaryColour=&H00FFFFFF,Outline=1,OutlineColour=&H00000000,Shadow=0.5,BackColour=&H00000000,MarginL=40,MarginR=40'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5b3ae1f8c5c0] Error parsing a filter description around: 
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5b3ae1f8c5c0] Error parsing filterchain`

(but this command was working with my default ffmpeg)

Comment: You'll probably need to quote the contents of force_style value.

Comment: the content is already quoted like that as I use it in Google Colab : 

`command = f"ffmpeg {cuda_option}-loglevel error -y -i input.mp4 -vf \"subtitles='{subtitles_srt}':force_style='FontName={font},FontSize={fontsize}'\" output.mp4"

subprocess.run(command)`

and it is working fine with these quotes when not using the cuda ffmpeg I compiled.