# Error parsing filterchain with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

My ffmpeg command

```
command = f"ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -loglevel error -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \"subtitles='subtitles.srt'\" output.mp4"
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

gives me the error

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5cdf3b4c7980] No option name near 'subtitles.srt'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5cdf3b4c7980] Error parsing a filter description around: 
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5cdf3b4c7980] Error parsing filterchain 'subtitles='subtitles.srt'' around: 
Failed to set value 'subtitles='subtitles.srt'' for option 'filter_complex': Invalid argument
Error parsing global options: Invalid argument
```

Using this version of ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version N-114442-g9df1182065 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
configuration: --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libfreetype --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --enable-libfreetype
libavutil      59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
libavcodec     61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
libavformat    61.  0.100 / 61.  0.100
libavdevice    61.  0.100 / 61.  0.100
libavfilter    10.  0.100 / 10.  0.100
libswscale      8.  0.100 /  8.  0.100
libswresample   5.  0.100 /  5.  0.100
```

Any idea why? It looks like a problem of quotes but this exact same command was working with a previous version of ffmpeg (not using Cuda).

If you want to try to replicate the problem, this is the code I use on google colab to install ffmpeg (it takes about 24 minutes to run):

```
!apt install nvidia-driver-525
!apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

!mkdir ~/nvidia/
%cd ~/nvidia/
!git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
%cd nv-codec-headers
!make install
%cd ~/nvidia/
!git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg/
!apt install build-essential yasm cmake libtool libc6 libc6-dev unzip wget libnuma1 libnuma-dev
%cd ~/nvidia/ffmpeg/

!./configure --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libfreetype --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64  --enable-libfreetype
!make -j $(nproc)

!ls -l ffmpeg
!./ffmpeg
!sudo make install

!ls -l /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
!type -a ffmpeg
!echo "$PATH"
!export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
!echo "$PATH"
%cd /content
```

Comment: Try: `command = f"ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -loglevel error -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \"subtitles=\"subtitles.srt\"\" output.mp4"` and `subprocess.run(shlex.split(command))`. I think that FFmpeg removes the `'`...`'` from `'subtitles.srt'` when executed from command line, but the `'`...`'` stays when using `subprocess.run(...)` from Python.

Comment: @Rotem looks better, I get back a CompletedProcess message, but my videos are still not processed and I get a 234 error code:

`CompletedProcess(args=['ffmpeg', '-hwaccel', 'cuda', '-loglevel', 'error', '-y', '-i', 'input.mp4', '-filter_complex', 'subtitles=subtitles.srt', 'output.mp4'], returncode=234)`

I have edited my post above with the code I use to install ffmpeg on colab so that you can easily try if you want.

Comment: Please limit your question to command line only. If you think the issue is related to Python, post a question in StackOverflow site. Is it working without `-hwaccel cuda`?

Comment: I have no idea whether or not this issue is related to Python but I’ll be happy to open another question if you tell me to do so. I get the same error without `-hwaccel cuda`. Subtitling is working with the default ffmpeg installed on Colab (without `-hwaccel cuda`). I can also use my cuda enabled ffmpeg (installed with the code above) with other commands . The only thing not working is subtitling with my cuda enabled ffmpeg (whether or not I use the `-hwaccel cuda` option)

Comment: From your description, it look like the issue is related to FFmpeg build configuration, or maybe missing installation of some libraries in Linux. I recommend you to post a new question in SuperUser with command line execution only: `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt" output.mp4`. I see you have asked about [drawtext] (https://superuser.com/q/1836546/635712) build configuration. Maybe the `subtitles` filter requires `--enable-libsrt`. I actually never tried building FFmpeg from sources.

Comment: ok i’ve done so here https://superuser.com/questions/1837109/ffmpeg-error-parsing-filterchain-subtitles

Comment: Try without the quotes: `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt output.mp4`

Comment: same problem without the quotes